# Environment variable to boolean in Python ( False in [0,"0"] == True )

Tags: python, environment-variables, boolean

I want to decide project's status (production/development) by checking if there is a `PRODUCTION` environment variable.

The problem is that, surprisingly, this code returns `True` when there is no `PRODUCTION` environment variable:

```
PRODUCTION = True if os.getenv('PRODUCTION', False) in [0,"0"] else False # !!! In Bash, 0 means true and 1 false
```

The thing is that `False in [0,"0"]` gives `True` which I didn't know until now. I know that `if 0` is the same as `if False` but this surprised me.

How to make it work and why it behaves like that?

EDIT

Solved this way but I'm still curious why the "in" statement works like that.

```
PRODUCTION = True if str(os.getenv('PRODUCTION', 1)) == "0" else False # !!! In Bash, 0 means true and 1 false
```

Comment: I think `in` is basically doing `==` comparisons (note that `False == 0` evaluates `True`) - you can get a similar thing if comparing between integers and (integer-valued) floats.

Comment: Can you please clarify what confuses you about the in operator? You seem to already know that False is equal to 0. So `False in [0,...]` because there is an element equal to False in the list.

Comment: Asked differently, what do you think the in operator is doing, and why do you think this means you "should" get a different result?

Comment: You're both right.. it does make sense.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you're reading from the environmental dict with `.get()`, you could instead index it and let it raise `KeyError`

```py
try:
    prod = bool(os.environ["PRODUCTION"] == PROD_FLAG)
except KeyError:  # PRODUCTION not in env dict
    prod = False
```

If you're really interested in forms of "false", stringify 'em

```
if "false" in [str(x).lower() for x in iterable]
```

The problem with your initial solution is that `0` is equal to `False` in Python, which is not immediately obvious

```py
>>> False == 0
True
>>> False in [0]
True
>>> False is 0
<stdin>:1: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
False
```

see also Falsey-ness which can bite you too [What is Truthy and Falsy? How is it different from True and False?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false)

Comment: This is *not* about falsy'ness. The empty list is falsy, but it is not in `[0, "0"]` and False is not in `[[], "0"]`.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi their `.getenv()` solution compares each value in `[0, "0"]` to `False`, and they're surprised the first is non-obviously `True`

Comment: Yes, and this is *not* due to falsy'ness. Most other falsy values will behave differently than 0 here.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean, indeed it's _equal_ to False (though not literally `is False` ..), rather than Falsey